# AWS IAM policy for security group not working

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-iam, aws-security-group

To implement [this](https://github.com/marketplace/actions/aws-security-group-add-ip), I created AWS Policy

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "UpdateIngress",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "ec2:RevokeSecurityGroupIngress",
                "ec2:AuthorizeSecurityGroupIngress"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:ec2:us-west-2:***:security-group/lc-github-action-ips"
        },
        {
            "Sid": "DescribeGroups",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "ec2:DescribeSecurityGroups",
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

Then assigned it to user. I tried to run following command to test this

```
aws ec2 describe-security-groups --filters Name=group-name,Values=lc-github-action-ips
```

But it didnt not return anything. If I run above command with admin user, it returns security group details in `Json`

Whats I am missing here ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems the user to whom you assigned the policy doesn't have programmatic access.

Created a new user and a new profile with the new user's access key id/secret access key in .aws/credentials file.

Ran the same command successfully as below with the new profile, keeping the policy, same (except region and account) as you shared.

```
aws ec2 describe-security-groups --filters Name=group-name,Values=lc-github-action-ips  --profile newuserprofile
```